# how do I create a horizontal scrolling Photo collection in Cocoa OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

If you look into the Compose View of the current Version of the Facebook iOS app, you will see that it has a horizontal scrolling View that shows attached Photos. In it you can not only scroll but also change the order of the photos via drag and drop. Can someone explain to me how I can create something similar in Cocoa OSX? Just the basics, which View could be the starting point for something like this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I would've started with an NSTableView rotated 90 degrees. Nowadays, NSCollectionView should be your starting point. You can get horizontal scrolling, NSCollectionViewCells in which to draw your photos, and editing behavior for re-ordering.

Comment: He or she is talking about OS X.  See the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an NSCollectionView.