# Writing a class that creates multiple interface objects in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, class

I'm writing an app for OS X that will have several vertical sliders that each have labels lined up with the tick marks and an NSTextField directly above it.  I need to do the placement of the labels programmatically to get them to line up.  So rather than do that for each and every slider, I thought it would be smart to write a class that does it, then I can just create 4 or 5 instances of that class and it will set up the UI for each slider.  Is this possible?  I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is a bit unclear from you description. It'd be good if you could provide more details and perhaps a screenshot as well.

You mention writing a class that and create some instances of it. You should ask yourself though, what is the conceptual importance of that class? In fact, I wouldn't go as far as creating a class for each group, just to position the controls. In this case, a simple method in your controller (or elsewhere) should be enough to instantiate, position and rig your controls up:

```
- (void)placeNewControlGroup
{
    // do the placement
    // set up bindings
    // rig actions etc.
}
```

Then whenever you need, you can call that method to create a new group of controls (i.e. slider, labels etc.).

Alternatively, you could make use of some of the standard views that Cocoa provides for handling collections. For instance, a `NSCollectionView` or view-based `NSTableView`. A nice video tutorial for the former can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw-sHMTsMVs).

For instance, creating an `NSCollectionView` and sizing it horizontally to fit your content (that is, your vertical sliders) might be a solution. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905019/how-do-i-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-photo-collection-in-cocoa-osx), a rotated `NSTableView` is proposed as well, which may turn out not to be a bad idea.

Comment: You're absolutely right about using a method rather than a class.  That slipped my mind.  I'll check out NSCollectionView and see if that helps me.